# How to setup PTR (Reverse DNS) at Godaddy DNS manager

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, reverse-dns, ptr-record

My hosting provider already did PTR setup. Now i have to setup it at my DNS holder i guess. What am i supposed to do at my Godaddy account. thank you.

my ip : 64.250.113.235

and you can check my ptr record from here

http://mxkit.com/webmaster-tools/ptr-check

result

Ptr records for 64.250.113.235 are: Server: 10.0.80.11 Address: 10.0.80.11#53

Non-authoritative answer: 235.113.250.64.in-addr.arpa name = notification.pokemoncraft.com.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add a PTR record in the GoDaddy DNS Manager, you need to do the following:

- In the Zone Field Editor go down to the TXT(text) Zone

  - Click Add SPF Record

A window will open with 4 tabs (Inbound, Outbound, The *well hidden* 'PTR' and Outsourced)

- Go to the PTR tab
- Check Include PTR and add your public IP

Comment: You now have to use the classic dns manager to get the spf option. The new dns zone file editor doesn't work this way.

Comment: The answer from Jan Mandel looks more accurate, while this answer looks wrong even though it is accepted.

Comment: WRONG ANSWER! "Do not use a PTR record to configure reverse DNS in our system"--Godaddy Help Page(https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-is-reverse-dns-2585) Jan Mandel's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 25):

Your hosting provider who owns the IP sets the PTR record for it. There is nothing to do in the DNS zone editor for your domain.

I have just done it. My hosting provider (digitalocean) automatically created PTR record when I named the host, it just needed to be the full name, ending with the domain. I added the IP in Godaddy's DNS editor. Now nslookup hostname and nslookup IP work just fine.

When I first called Godaddy support they tried to sell me "premium DNS". But unless they own the IP, they could not set the PTR record anyway.

(I know this is old thread but it does come up in google search)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an A record pointing notification.pokemoncraft.com to 64.250.113.235.  This can be done from the GoDaddy hosting control panel under DNS.

Comment: ok i did that. lets see will it work :) and thanks for the answer

Comment: @mrdenny it still says Non-authoritative answer:  here how i setup A record http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/971/arecords.png

Comment: That is correct.  It will say non-authoritative answer unless the DNS server that you are querying is the authoritative server.

Comment: Non-authoritative answer is completely normal. It means that you got a reply from a cache, and not directly from the Authorative server.

Comment: can you check for me that my ptr is correctly setup now or not . ip : 64.250.113.235   the email i use to send emails via smtp : notification@pokemoncraft.com

Comment: yes it appears that it is.  When I do an nslookup for the IP address, I get back the correct domain name.

Comment: @mrdenny  thanks . can anyone else check too if possible ? i just want to be 100% sure

Comment: You guys clearly don't know what Reverse-DNS is.  This answer is 100% false.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the IP address space through your NIC organization, then you might need to provide the DNS services for PTR zones (those are inverted resolutions from IP to name). I can confirm, for LACNIC, that is the case, but it seems GoDaddy does not support creating those zones.

In reality, GoDaddy has a crappy DNS service. Not even their import tools work and is documented all over the web.

Consider using other services like Azure or AWS for such DNS zones.

And as Jan said, you might need to work with your ISP if they own the IP address segment. They are the ones providing those DNS services.