# Reverse DNS PTR entries matching to MX entries

Tags: domain-name-system, email, ptr-record

Confusion over what reverse DNS applies to and where it gets set...  Although [there are answers on how to do this](https://serverfault.com/questions/219779/how-to-setup-ptr-reverse-dns-at-godaddy-dns-manager), I still cannot determine what needs to get done and why.

A domain is registered at Registrar A, which holds the DNS tables.
Registrar A also serves up mail services via the Registrar's owned domain.
Two VPS serve different 3rd level domain services.

The spf record in DNS table points to the domain of the mail server for MX services, while the MX record points to

```
mail.registeredDomain.com

v=spf1 a mx ptr include:mailServer.net ~all
```

MX toolbox states `Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner`

are reverse DNS lookups based on the service (mx) or the domain?
I can see the mismatch with MX record, but the mail provider had instructions to set up PTR record as stated.

How should the SPF PTR record be set? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Reverse DNS records does not have anything to do with Your domain records

Lets say your domain is company.com. You have SOA, NS, MX, A and TXT -SPF records defined, pointing to an IP address of Yours.

The reverse zones for an IP address works like any other domain name lookup, but are located in domain suffix `.in-addr.arpa` . The domain delegation for sub domains under "in-addr.arpa" is not to be mixed up with the .com, .net  etc.

Normally the "owners" of a subdomain to in-addr.arpa is the ISP owning the address space. So to get a correct DNS reverse lookup for "your" IP-address, you must ask your ISP to set it, or ask that you  get an delagation for your subnet and add it to your own public dns.

And for your SPF PTR question, see [open SPF syntax guide](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

> If at all possible, you should avoid using this mechanism in your SPF record, because it will result in a larger number of expensive DNS lookups.

Comment: the ISP of the mail server I assume.  correct?

Comment: to find the "owner" of an IP address reverse zone, check  (example)
dig  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.
It shows ; 
AUTHORITY SECTION:
8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. 60 IN SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 221575125 900 900 1800 60 
So if you check the same with Your IP-adderss, you find whos is responsible for the reverse zone

Comment: remember to add a dot "." after .in-addr.arpa in the request

Comment: Or just do    dig -x <my.ip.add.ress>

Comment: On the other hand, a missmatch of PTR record and FQDN of the mail host is NOT a serious matter. Most mailservers except gmail, hotmail, etc  are in this situation